# Replace everything after last forward slash

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am attempting to remove everything after the last forward slash in my URL.  I wrote some REGEX that works in the [online](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) Java REGEX testers, but unfortunately does not in my local code.  Any insight in to why this may be would be greatly appreciated.  Right now my REGEX pattern, target string, and desired output are as follows.

```
Regular Expression: "[^/]*$"
Target String: /example/c/coffee101
Desired Output: /example/c/cafè999
```

The bare-bones Java code:

```
target = "/example/c/coffee101";
replace = "cafè999";
target.replaceFirst("[^/]*$", replace);
```

Thank you greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `replaceFirst` method to `target` as no method in `String` class changes the String object itself:

```
target = target.replaceFirst("[^/]*$", replace);
```

Comment: One of us needs to get off of the regex tag for the night ;) just kidding, have my upvote (I'm going on vacation in an hour anyways!).

Comment: Thank you so much. I get so caught up on the REGEX itself I overlook the actual function.

Comment: @user1615559: it's not necessarily about the function and what the return says on it, but about the fact that `String` objects are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though [`.replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-) returns the modified string..try:

```
target = target.replaceFirst("[^/]*$", replace);
```

---

> **Returns**
>
> The string constructed by replacing the first matching subsequence by the replacement string, substituting captured subsequences as needed

Comment: Thank you so much. Getting too caught up in why the REGEX may be wrong and forget to actually think about the function itself.